# Get Standard User Profile Id no matter what the users language is

Tags: soql, salesforcedx, profile, scratch-org

When a (scratch) org is created by a non-english user this query will have no results:

```
[SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='Standard User']
```

Instead you have to use a localized name (here in German)

```
[SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='Standardbenutzer']
```

**Is there a bullet-proof way to SOQL `Standard User` and `System Administrator` without taking care of language differences?**

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I'd describe it as bullet proof, but you could query that associated PermissionSet records.

At the minimum you can narrow things down with:

- PermissionSet.IsOwnedByProfile = true
- PermissionSet.IsCustom = false

That should give you the core Profiles as a starting point. 
Then it might become a bit of a slog to identify which Permissions each of those profiles is expected to have. I'm not sure it would be 100% reliable, but it might get you close enough to find the correct profile you need.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could set a Savepoint, change the user's language to English, do your query and then rollback the DML transaction? That's a bit heavy in real orgs and could have side effects, but could be OK in a scratch org or unit test.

Frankly though it's silly that Profiles still don't have both a Name and Developer Name.